# Apache error log; Php error file does not exist; Think it has something to do with mod_rewrite

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I get a whole bunch of these errors, but with different ad id:s in the end. The one below has ad id "Bmw_m3_brand_new_2939822"

```
[Fri Oct 29 22:57:37 2010] [error] [client 111.111.11.11] File does not exist: /var/www/annons, referer: http://www.domain.se/annons/Bmw_m3_brand_new_2939822
```

Everything works fine on the website. But I still get a whole lot of errors in the error.log file of apache2.

Anybody know anything about this?

I have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess FYI. And it is ok, without errors, I am sure.
So I wonder, what is causing all these errors in the log file?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

The IPS of the clients in the errors seem to come from valid Internet Providers. Even my Own IP adress is located in the errors list, though I haven't received any 404 or errors when visiting the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's standard [referrer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam).

Comment: Are you sure? Sites only been up a month. Care to explain more in detail?

Comment: Is your site linked anywhere? Can they be found by some search engines? If you answered yes to one or both of the questions, this is normal referrer spam.

Comment: The IP:S seem to come from valid Internet Providers here in Sweden. Still think it is spam? Btw, if so, how can I prevent it? Im kindof new to servers, and I have my own Virtual Private Server.

Comment: You can't really pro-actively prevent that kind of spam. You can only react to it by blocking the offending clients (e. g. by their IP addresses or by filtering the HTTP referrer value).

Answer (score 0):

It maybe hackers attack, investigate IPs.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to believe that.