# Awstats showing strange 404 referrers

Tags: http-status-code-404, awstats

When I look at Awstats 404 errors I see sometimes strange referrers.
For example on www.mydomain.com I might see a 404 error reported in Awstats that says:

```
URL (not found)        Referrers
some-file.jpg          http://www.mydomain.com/some-page.html
```

`some-file.jpg` is a file that does not exist, so it's not strange that if someone tried to reach it got back a 404 from server.

The strange part is that the referring page DOES NOT EXIST TOO, I mean `http://www.domain.com/some-page.html` DOES NOT EXIST, so how could it be the referrer?

Is it some client cheating the referrer?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this question and it's answers http://serverfault.com/questions/196323/apache-error-log-php-error-file-does-not-exist-think-it-has-something-to-do-wit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Referrer Spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spam) is where a spammer sends fake Referrer data to see if it ends up in the referrers section of your public web-pages showing your standard web-log analyses (e.g "Top Referrers"). If the fake referrer does become visible, the spammer know they can use this technique to place spam links into your web-site causing visitors to your site to see links to their spam sites.